# Issue Deploying Google Charts

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint, google-visualization

I am in the process of deploying a set of **Google Charts** into SharePoint 2013. I am running into this issue where it isn't loading my data. I have tested it out in just a standard application page and it works perfectly. I will show my code below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     //approver chart
     var chartDataApprover; // globarlvariable to hold chart data
     google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });

     $(document).ready(function () {

         $.ajax({
             url: "Chart_Application_Page.aspx/GetChartDataApprover",
             data: "",
             dataType: "json",
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
             success: function (data) {
                 chartDataApprover = data.d;
             },
             error: function () {
                 alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
             }
         }).done(function () {
             //after data is loaded
             google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartApprover);
             drawChartApprover();
         });
     });
</script>

     //approver function
     function drawChartApprover() {
         var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartDataApprover);

         //groups chart data by name
         var resultApprover = google.visualization.data.group(data, [0], [{ 'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number' }]);

         var options = {
             title: "Approver Spending",
             pointSize: 5
         };
         var pieChartApprover = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_approver'));
         pieChartApprover.draw(resultApprover, options);
     }
```

I believe my error is coming on the line where I am setting the **content type**. I am deploying this into SharePoint 2013 via an Application Page... with code behind in **C#**.

Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: What's the error and what is the code causing the error?

Comment: It is giving me my alert that says "Error loading data", it runs, just doesn't load data. And as I said above, the code causing the error I believe is where I am setting the content type...